# Server with RAID10 basic partition management

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid10, partition

First of all i must say that i'm totally noob to server management.
I've rented a server with 8x3TB HDs and RAID10 installed.

In the Disk Management section (I use windows server) i see two unallocated blocks of 2Tbs and 10Tbs each one. I guess this is normal because the RAID10 gives me only half the amount of disk space i've rented.

So now my question is... if i create a partition, that partition will automatically have a duplication of the data or do i have to do something more?

Thanks in advance for any help/hints.

Comment: Ah... and i've just seen i can only create a simple volume for the 2Tb unallocated memory and i have no option to create a volume with the 10Tb unallocated memory, why is that?

Comment: I take it the RAID is done in software RAID? Something starts to ring a bell with the boot volume using MBR and only being able to use boot volumes up to 2TB...any more than that and you'll need GPR instead. Could you upload a picture of your Disk Management screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data will be automatically duplicated on the mirrored sets. You don't have to do anything extra.

> Ah... and i've just seen i can only create a simple volume for the 2Tb
>   unallocated memory and i have no option to create a volume with the
>   10Tb unallocated memory, why is that?

Because MBR (master boot record) volumes can be a maximum of 2TB. For larger volumes, you need to go GPT (guid partition table.)

Comment: My problem now is that i only have one Disk (and has the OS installed in one partition) so i can't convert that disk into GPT. Is there anything i could do about it?